# Vue data-binding in axios response is not updating in view

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to create a new item. After created successfully I need to update the item list. When I set the item list from server it fails to update in view.

```
<v-btn @click="create(item)" >
</v-btn>
```

```
data: () => ({
  items: [],
})
methods: {
  create (item) {
    createItem(item).then(response => {
      this.scene = this.scenes.list
      this.item = null
      var options = {
        page: 0,
        itemsPerPage: 10,
      }
      getItems(options).then(function (response) {
        this.items= response.content
      }.bind(this))
    })
},
}
```

When I debug, 'this.items= response.content' is successfuly set. But in view the data is not updated. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you bind `this` to another context, `this.items` is no longer referring to the Vue instance, thus it won't update.

Declare the Vue instance to another variable before `createItem`, and you should be able to use it:

```
data: () => ({
  items: [],
})
methods: {
  create (item) {
    const vm = this;
    createItem(item).then(response => {
      this.scene = this.scenes.list
      this.item = null
      var options = {
        page: 0,
        itemsPerPage: 10,
      }
      getItems(options).then(function (response) {
        vm.items= response.content
      }.bind(this))
    })
},
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a scope(`this`) issue, Simply you can use arrow function in the response or also you can use async/await approach.

```
getItems(options).then(response => {
   this.items = response.content
})
```

```
async create (item) {
   try {
     const itemResponse = await createItem(item)
     this.scene = this.scenes.list
     this.item = null
     const options = { page: 0, itemsPerPage: 10 }
     const response = await getItems(options)
     this.items = response.content
   } catch() {
      console.log(err)
   }
}
```